# Star Trek episode where the crew is incapacitated on the bridge

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, episode-identification, star-trek-enterprise

I'm trying to recall a *Star Trek* episode (either Voyager or Enterprise) from a specific action scene.  My impression is that the crew is on the bridge, and some threat is causing them to be incapacitated.  They have to flee, but the helmsman (either Paris or Mayweather) loses consciousness.  Someone who usually sits at the rear of the bridge (like Tuvok or T'Pol) is barely able to crawl across the bridge, reach the conn station, and saves the ship.  It could have been the captain who saves the day.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is [VOY: One](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/One_(episode)). The episode opens with the crew on the bridge suffering from the effects of a nebula they've just entered. Tuvok manages to cross the bridge and change the course so that it leads them away.

[image]

He's not *crawling*, but everyone else is and he's clearly well on his way to falling down.

Comment: Ah, "One", the episode that stole the title that the amazing "Drone" should have had ;)

Comment: That's the one!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It could also be STE episode where due to negative effects due to radiation from (iirc) trinary system with a black hole and 2 stars which they were exploring.

Crew is starting to exhibit strange behavior and, eventually, whole crew is incapacitated to the point where they all have to go under medical suspension (or induced coma or similar) except for T'Pol.

Ship is programmed to navigate trough shortest path that leads to space outside of radiation field of influence but in the end T'Pol has to wake up Captain Archer to manually pilot the ship trough the debris field of accretion disc,

(I think that's the first episode that they use "Red Alert" System that Reed implemented which later became standard procedure for Starfleet).

All of the crew is incapacitated and have to go under suspension except for T'Pol, in the end she has to wake up Captain Archer to manually pilot the ship through the debris field of accretion disc or something similar, and I think that's the first episode that they actually use "Red Alert" System that Reed implemented.

Just found the ep name, it's [STE:Singularity](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Singularity_(episode))

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(Star_Trek:_Enterprise)

Comment: Looks like you repeated yourself there. Looks like you accidentally repeated yourself there.

Comment: Thanks FreeMan yea I did, just removed the one line.

Comment: @FreeMan It's a time loop.